# JQuery hide list elements by partial class name

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I need to find and hide all li tags in my page that have the partial class of 'fos-crs-'.

```
<li class="minimal-product-wrapper toggle-container fos-crs-XXX">...<li>
```

where the XXX is some course-code that comes from a database call.  The "fos-crs" class is one I added so I can specifically find and manipulate these specific li tags. The other classes in the li tags are part of work created by off-site developers using Foundation.  In other areas these have not been a problem for my JQuery.

I have tried:

```
$('[class^="fos-crs-"]').hide();

... and ...

$('li[class^="fos-crs-"]').hide();
```

Would someone tutor me in this?  Much appreciated.

Comment: Is your script invoked after the elements is loaded (at the bottom of the body)?

Comment: Thanks!  Yes, the are on the page pre-hiding attempts.  I can see the codes via view-source and FireBug.  I cannot find any other code that would interfere with these or make them show after I hide them.  Has to be something soooo simple.  Sigh!

Comment: fixed. It was me!  I found a separate function that is somehow being called. It is "showing" all courses.  So, I think my hiding code worked, but this other function is being called and un-hiding them.  Thanks for the help though.  Made me think and relook at the code differently.

Answer (score 2):

You are targeting the class that `starts with`(^) operator. Rather you should target with `any occurrence`(*).
i.e,

```
 $('li[class^="fos-crs-"]').hide();
```

should be

```
$('li[class*="fos-crs-"]').hide();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d4uk2fmg/

Answer (score 1):

The attribute selector looks at the entire attribute, not each class in the attribute. So what you're code is looking for is elements whose class attribute starts with "fos-crs". You need to check if that string is contained within the attribute at all, so you need the `*` modifier.

```js
$('li[class*="fos-crs-"]').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li class="minimal-product-wrapper toggle-container fos-crs-XXX">...<li>
    <li class="minimal-product-wrapper toggle-container fos-crs-XXX">...<li>
    <li class="minimal-product-wrapper toggle-container fos-crs-XXX">...<li>
    <li class="minimal-product-wrapper toggle-container">...<li>
</ul>
```